# Finding Sub-documents through dot notation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a simplified collection structure below for simplicity's sake. I am unable to query the specific sub-documents under the profile field.

For example, I want to find the sub-document "profiles.Bernie". Is there a find() query that will allow me to only retrieve the document for Bernie (i.e. category and id for Bernie)? Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I was unable to find solutions that catered the way this collection is structured below

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56aec822ceb6e9dc23d32271"),
        "sm_user" : "user1",
        "profiles" : {
                "Bernie" : {
                        "category" : "Politics",
                        "id" : "bernie"
                },
                "Hilary" : {
                        "category" : "Politics",
                        "id" : "hilary"
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can choose to just get the `Bernie` subtree and suppress the normally included `_id`;

```
db.test.find({},{ _id:0, "profiles.Bernie":1 })
```

This *will* include the structure leading up to `Bernie` (aka the `profiles` tag), but only the data from that subtree.

If you don't want the structure to remain, you could also use the aggregate framework to project `Bernie` to the root of the output document;

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project: { _id:0, 'Bernie': "$profiles.Bernie"}}])
```

Comment: That's perfect, I was having a brain fart. I forgot about the projection parameters. Thanks so much!